# Hide auto suggest popup while pressing CTRL in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, visibility, autosuggest

A functionality I constantly use on **Visual Studio** without even realizing it is that when I hold the `CTRL` key, the popup's opacity diminishes, allowing me to see the code that was hidden by the popup.
[image: Popup visible when not pressing CTRL]

And when I press and hold `CTRL`

[image: Popup transparent when pressing CTRL]

Is there a way to have the same thing in **Visual Studio Code**? (either built-in or an extension)